# Stuck in console in debian 11

Tags: debian

I recently installed debian 11  while installing I wasn't connected wifi due to which I don't got an option to choose desktop environment

so I have to login into Console
I tried to install Kde plasma , Kde standard
but I failed

I tried exit console using ctrl+alt+ F1, F2 and all f keys one by one

please help me

I am new in debian and Linux world

Comment: How did you fail? Does `startx` start a graphical interface? What is the result of `dpkg -l | grep 'plasma\|xorg'`?

Answer (score 0):

To exit from the console you just type `exit`.

Don't panic :-)

If you just installed Debian, and got it wrong, I would simply do it again; following the [Installation Guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/installmanual) carefully. It's a good learning process!

If you want to try to fix the install you already have, you need network functionality.

- If you haven't got that try to run [nmtui](https://www.tecmint.com/nmtui-configure-network-connection/), it's a text-based user interface for NetworkManager and if you have that installed you should be okay. Otherwise you probably have `iw` installed, and the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration/Wireless#iw) should be of help
- And if you have network, then [configure apt](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apbs04.en.html#preseed-apt), and use that to [install KDE](https://wiki.debian.org/KDE) again.

It may be a good idea to say hello to the folks at https://forums.debian.net - and really, don't panic; if you just left MS-Windows and started on Linux, then that's a bit like [choosing the red pill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_pill_and_blue_pill) :-D It may be a bit bumpy to begin with - but: Welcome to freedom, and relax and enjoy the ride!

Edit: @wasiq, I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I answer you here - your error "package not located" sounds like something `apt`could say; are you connected to the internet? Try `ping 1.1.1.1` to check. If not, you need to get your network up and running. And as you are stranded on the console, outside the Debian installer, I'd recommend checking the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration/Wireless). But even better; I think you should just start over. You'll just give yourself a bad start with Linux if you try to install it manually, having only little experience (if you really want to install Linux manually, I'd absolutely would recommend using Arch instead - but you shouldn't, so I don't :-)

Answer (score 0):

reinstall, but when you're at "select and install software" install with recommended software, this will install a gui for you