# stuck in debian console

Tags: debian, apt

so I asked this question before but nothing helped me

I installed and dual boot debian 11 on my laptop

while installing I wasn't able to select desktop environment (GUI) then it booted into Console I tried to install kde-plasma but it says

```
e: unable to locate package
```

I searched about this on internet

I found that my sources.list is causing this problem then I cleared my sources.list and added these line to sources.list

```
   deb http://deb.debian.org/debian- 
   bullseye/ bullseye main
   deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian- 
   bullseye/ bullseye main
   deb http://deb.debian.org/debian- 
   bullseye/ bullseye-updates 
   main
  deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian- 
   bullseye/ bullseye-updates 
   main
```

then I tried to run

```
  sudo apt update
```

I got this

```
w: failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease
```

I searched internet for this but none of them worked for me
please help

Comment: Have you checked wether your ntw-interfaces are up (ip, netstat, ifconfig etc.. systemctl status networkd) ? Try pinging or tracerouting some ip's?

Comment: Agreed, I imagine your machine is not on the internet.

Comment: I was connected  with the ethernet

Comment: Being physically connected to an ethernet cable does not mean that you have a connection to the internet.

Comment: `ip route` please [edit] your question for output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stuck in console in debian 11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687431/stuck-in-console-in-debian-11). If not, then add any additional details to *that* question, rather than posting the same question again.